# High capacitance oscillator circuit to produce longitudinal waves

Tags: oscillator

I’m trying to figure out a suitable oscillator circuit to produce longitudinal electric field waves (like in a Tesla Coil) to experiment and produce any mechanical or EM effects on various materials.  A conductive sphere will be driven with AC. So the sphere will be pulsing  with –q , +q , -q , ... with an isometric pure electrodynamic field with all magnetic  field cancelled out.

A 50 Mhz fixed frequency oscillator circuit with weak or no harmonic distortion to oscillate relatively high amount of charges  back and forth to a high capacitance sphere antenna (sphere, because i know the self-capacitance equation of a sphere only). I think a crystal/Pierce oscillator would fit best for a fixed high frequency without harmonic distortions. 
The problem is, I would need to oscillate  high amount of charges (about 10^-5 – 10^-4 Coulombs) to produce a decent, mechanical or EM effect.

To drive such high amplitude of oscillations with peak voltages low enough to be safely measured even with a 10x oscilloscope probe, I would need a high capacitance oscillator circuit and I think that even if I connected many crystals in parallel, I would need thousands of them.

Could I use a thick crystal with low fundamental frequency and produce only a higher harmonic (50MHz) by a band-pass circuit? But then again, why would I need a crystal when I used a resonant LC circuit with high capacitance?

Also I would need to be able adjust the amplitude of the oscillations (amount of oscillating charges) which makes things even more complicated. Should I vary the collector voltage of the transistor or the resistance?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Maxwell's equations pretty much say that for a electromagnetic field to propagate,the electromagnetic field will be orthogonal to the direction of propagation–ie. **not** longitudinal. You can of course let an electric field oscillate linearly,but that is not going to be a wave,but an excited oscillation within a conductor.Note that from Maxwell it's clear as daylight there can not be something like a electrodynamic wave without the matching magnetic one–that'd directly contradict Faraday's Law of induction.

Comment: You can try to achieve \$\mathbf J = - \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial\mathbf E}{\partial t}\$, but I'd a bit curious about the material where that would happen.

Comment: Point is that this will only happen in extremely interesting plasmas, metamaterial, or, classically, as longitudinal modes in cavities/waveguides.

Answer (score 1):

In spite of great drama around these Longitudinal waves, show me one authentic report of a measurement of a longitudinal wave.  I have done many tests with all kinds of microwave Network Analyzers and antenna and never seen or read a confirmed measurement.

I believe you can get longitudinal acoustic waves in a plasma detonation at the same time, but that's all.  Bearden et al has never produced any such evidence.

other ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave#Electromagnetic

> Do you have any measurement specs you want to generate at all ?

- Xtals have high Q >10k for AT cut, >> 100K for SC cut
- LC oscillators are have Q < 200, unless precision Helix maybe 500 under pristine conditions
- For high Xtal's get a fish finder transducer and couple impedance to a fluid properly

Russia's nuclear powered VLF experiments were not longitudinal but transverse like everything else.